# Javascript can't find ID of div inside user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, contentplaceholder, coda-slider

I have coda slider that i put inside a user control (ascx file) and it is working perfectly on a test page.

But when I put the same user control in a content place holder in a test page that is based on a master page it stops working correctly.  It appears that the javascript function can't correctly identify the ID of the DIV now that it inside of a content place holder.  I have read some other links but they seem to be slightly different situations and I have tried using document.getElementById, but not sure if I am on the right track or just messing up with the syntax. and I have also tried putting ct100_cpMC_ in front of the id.

```
<%@ Page Title="TestPage - Test User Control" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="_TestPage" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/WhatCustomersAreSaying.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WhatCustomersAreSaying" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/coda-slider.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.coda-slider-3.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
     $(function () {

         $('#slider-id').codaSlider({
               autoSlide:true,
               autoHeight:false
         });
     });
</script> 
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMC" Runat="Server">

    <uc1:WhatCustomersAreSaying runat="server" ID="WhatCustomersAreSaying" />

</asp:Content>
```

Inside my user control is a DIV with the ID of "slider-id" that the javascript function needs to find.

As I mentioned before, I am not sure if I need to use document.getElementById and how, or if there is a simpler way by prepending something to ID within quotes $('#slider-id') so the javascript function knows the ID it is looking for is within a content place holder.

Comment: Try `$("div[id*='slider-id']")`

Comment: This technique did not work for me, same results as before.  All the content for all divs are showing and basically the slider is not working it it should.

Comment: Run your aspx page; In the browser check the source (CTRL+U); Check the generated id of the slider; Is it _really_ `slider-id`?

Comment: I checked the source, and that is the ID.  <div class="coda-slider"  id="slider-id">,  But the DIV is inside a user control and the javascript is inside the parent page.  Everything works when I use a test page that is not using a master page

Comment: Lets start with a checklist: Do you have any JavaScript errors in the page? Is the document ready function firing? Does the `document.get.elementById('')` return `undefined` ?

Comment: I am not currently using document.get.elementByID.  When I try it the way GEMI mentions I do not see any errors in visual studio error list. I previously tried to add something like this to the javascript funciton, which did not work either.         $(function () {
                 var slidername = document.getElementById("slider-id"); 
             $(slidername).codaSlider({

Comment: Also how do I check if the document ready function is firing?  The javascript function works when the test page is not part of a master page and user control is in a content place holder.

Comment: Check your browser console, and verify that you have no javascript error. Add an alert before  $('#slider-id').codaSlider... and verify that the your code is reached.

Comment: I do have the following javascript error(and I confirmed that I do not have this or any javascript errors on the test page that is not using a master page). TypeError: $(...).codaSlider is not a function @ http://localhost:56374/TestPage.aspx:71.  Also I put an alert right before $('#slider-id').codaSlider and the alert box shows up.

Comment: Actually when I add what GEMI suggested - document.get.elementById('') I get 2 javascript warnings and the undefined error you mentioned.  Here are is what is in javascript tab of web console. 1. The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating. 2.  FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().3.  TypeError: document.get is undefined.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a friend help me and this is what worked.  I knew I needed the (document).ready but did not have the syntax correctly.  This is what fixed my problem,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function ($) {
         $('#slider-id').codaSlider({
             autoSlide:true,
             autoHeight:false
         });
     });
</script>
```